# Saving files causes vim to freeze

Tags: vim

I'm having a problem with saving in vim.  When I try to save with `:w`, it is extremely slow. Generally taking 15-20 seconds to save.  During that time, I can't interact with vim at all.

I've tried `set nobackup`, and it helped a little bit, but it's still slow.  The file I'm trying to write is only 526 bytes.  I'm able to create files of similar size through other mechanisms, like sending stdout to a file or using a different editor, without any problems.  It's just Vim that's super slow.

It started fairly recently. I can't think of any changes that may have cause it.
 [Here's my vimrc file](https://pastebin.com/mdFFVet8).  Anything that could be causing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest running Vim with an empty config:

```
vim -u NONE
```

Then see if this behavior is still there. If it is, there may be something wrong with you Vim installation or file system.

If the problem vanishes, comment out all plugins and autocmds and re-enable them one by one. Rinse and repeat until you hit the problem again. You will then have found the setting or plugin causing it.

Comment: I ran this and still have the problem. So should I try reinstalling vim?

Comment: I would check your filesystem first, then completely remove Vim and install it again. Which platform are you on? Also, which Vim version? `vim -v`

Comment: running an Ubuntu 16.04 server instance in Openstack

Comment: I have no experience with OpenStack. Is the file system local or network-mounted?

Comment: not sure, honestly. But I actually just reinstalled vim and it does seem to have solved the problem.

Comment: The only reason I could think of right now is a non-local file system. You could alternatively try Neovim and see if the issue appears there as well.

Comment: nevermind, the problem occurred again after reinstalling and saving a couple of times.

Comment: If the issue is with the filesystem, can you explain why vim is the only program that has problems saving?

Comment: As I'm not too familiar with other editors, I can only guess that it's probably because Vim writes a swap file by default. If that swap file (which is essentially a copy of the edited file) fills up the disk before the actual save, I can see how this would collide when your disk space is extremely low, like in the single byte range. Other editors like nano don't do that and simply overwrite in-place.

Comment: hmm, I ran the above command and it fixed it, so i went to ~/.vimrc and commented out all the lines and it didn't fix it, I also did the same thing in global vimrc file located at /etc/vim/vimrc and still same problem. Any other file that -u NONE removes?